# Does using the ZAAZ-20K engages over 90% of one's muscles?

Tags: healthcare

I read on http://zaazmovement.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ZAAZ-20K-User-Manual1.compressed.pdf ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170924065952/http://zaazmovement.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/ZAAZ-20K-User-Manual1.compressed.pdf)):

> Standing on a ZAAZ vibration plate stimulates all parts of the body. **12 minutes on the machine engages over 90% of your muscles** by causing up to 30 muscle contractions per second. Research shows that WBV can have profound impacts on circulation, weight management conditioning and pain relief.

Is it true that the using ZAAZ-20K engages over 90% of one's muscles? I couldn't find the research studies they mention.

Given that [there are ~640-850 muscles in the human body](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_skeletal_muscles_of_the_human_body&oldid=776272571), 90% of them sounds like a lot to me.

Comment: Note that there is an questionable implication made in the claim: that "engag(ing) over 90% of your muscles" does something useful. *Taking a walk* engages muscles, but it won't make you look like a fitness model. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @JaredSmith Correct, just checking if it does engage over 90% of one's muscles.

Comment: I doubt we'll ever find a study to cite that wasn't paid for by the manufacturer (if they even bothered). My best guess is that the explicit claim is trivially true, and the implied connection to actual fitness results is false. Note also that the 'over 90%' claim could be referring to *mass*, there's a few muscles (quads and lats come to mind) that account for a disproportionate share of muscle mass.